# Matrix multiplication returning wrong matrix python parallel

Tags: python, matrix, multiprocessing, multiplication

I have a school project, where I have to do some python parallel function. One of them is matrix multiplication(I cannot use numpy). I tried to do it in multithreading, but it was too slow and I was recommented to do it in multiprocessing. It is much faster, but there is one problem. I get the right matrix only when I use one process. Can anyone help? Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp

min = -10
max = 10
n = 10
x = ((np.random.rand(n, n) * (max - min) ) + min).astype('int')
y = ((np.random.rand(n, n) * (max - min) ) + min).astype('int')

z = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
jump = 0

def matrixMult(start):
    for i in range(start, start + jump):
        print("HEJ")
        for k in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                z[i][j] += x[i][k] * y[k][j]

def multPrepare(x, y, i):
    pool = mp.Pool(i)
    pool.map(matrixMult, range(0, n, jump))
    return z

if __name__ == '__main__':

    i = 1
    while i < 5:
        start_time = time.time()
        jump = int(round(n / i))
        z = multPrepare(x, y, i)
        print("number of cores: " + str(i) + ", TIME: "+ str(time.time()-start_time) + " seconds")
        i += 1

    print(z)
    print(z == x.dot(y))
```

The result matrix is only right when i = 1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify: you wrote "I cannot use numpy" but then `import numpy as np` - what is right?

Comment: Well I cannot use numpy's function dot or matmul for multiplying the matrixes, I use it just to create matrixec and verify the result.